# How can I create a new StackOverflow tag without first posting?

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to create a new tag before posting a question that uses that tag? I was trying to setup an IFTTT recipe for a non-existent tag so that I can receive any questions marked with that tag by mail but it seems the tag needs to exist first. So I'm forced to create a 'fake' question like this one. Is there a better way?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. However, I need 5 reputation points to post there so that's not an option for me.

Comment: You now have 6, go post over there! :P

Comment: 6? I see 4. For whatever reason, people are enjoying downvoting. Not a very positive first impression of stack overflow I must say :-| But thanks all the same for your help

Comment: _"Not a very positive first impression of stack overflow I must say :-|"_ - well, maybe try to make a better first impression yourself. We don't post questions _about_ Stack Overflow _on_ Stack Overflow, that's what Meta is for. Your question has now been migrated, and welcome, anyway.

Comment: I needed 5 reputation points to post on Meta which I didn't have at the beginning so I don't get what you mean by 'make a better first impression'. Anyway, thanks for migrating the question. That was kind of you.